# Airflow Task Failed without empty Log and doesn't send email

Tags: task, operator-keyword, airflow

I have a DAG with 60 tasks (PythonsOperators) and in some executions different tasks are marked as failed, but I don’t know the reason, when I go to "View Log" the log is empty and when i pass over the red square it says Operator:null what does that mean?

It seems like it hasn't executed the task, but I don't understand why.

The questions are:

Why Airflow mark it as failed but there is no execution showed on log?
Why hasn't it send email of error if the tasks it's marked as failed?

Here is the python code associated to the dag:

```
DEFAULT_ARGS = {
'owner': 'blablabla',
'depends_on_past': False,
'start_date': datetime(2018, 5, 8),
'catchup': False,
'email': ['mail@mail.com'],
'email_on_failure': True,
'email_on_retry': False,
'retries': 3,
'max_active_runs': 1,
'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5)
}

dag = DAG('dag_name',
default_args=DEFAULT_ARGS,
schedule_interval='20 0 * * *')

mylist = get_codes_list()

for item in mylist:
healthcheckerName = 'healthchecker_' + item

healthchecker = PythonOperator(
dag=dag,
task_id=healthcheckerName,
python_callable=prime_ops.check_last_budget_calculation(item),
queue=SPECIFIC_QUEUE,
pool=DEFAULT_PPC_POOL
)
```

Answer (score 3):

The worker may die. I would suggest increase the memory allocation.

> If a worker dies before the buffer flushes, logs are not emitted. Task failure without logs is an indication that the Airflow workers are restarted due to out-of-memory (OOM).
>   You can read more here [Task fails without emitting logs](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/troubleshooting-dags#task_fails_without_emitting_logs).

Comment: where is this worker?  How do I check if this is indeed the cause>

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me. I found that some worker nodes were out of disk space, so they were failing tasks because they couldn't write the log.

Go into the Docker container for the worker node and search logs/worker.log for "No space left on device".

If this is the case, there are a couple of easy ways to mitigate:

1. Manually delete log files older than a certain date; or
2. Kill and restart the affected Docker containers. This is what we ended up doing. You do lose ALL of your worker logs if you do this.

Longer term it might be worthwhile to do log rotation or some automated cleanup of log files (oldest first).